# Which characters does NSLineBreakByWordWrapping break on?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

**Short version**

From the docs:

> `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`
>
> Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line.

What is the set of all word boundary characters?

**Longer version**

I have a set of UILabels, which contain text, sometimes including URLs.  I need to know the exact location (`frame`, not `range`) of the URLs so that I can make them tappable.  My math mostly works, but I had to build in a test for certain characters:

```
    // This code only reached if the URL is longer than the available width
    NSString *theText = // A string containing an HTTP/HTTPS URL
    NSCharacterSet *breakChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?-"];
    NSString *charsInRemaininsSpace = // NSString with remaining text on this line

    NSUInteger breakIndex = NSNotFound;
    
    if (charsInRemaininsSpace)
        breakIndex = [charsInRemaininsSpace rangeOfCharacterFromSet:breakChars
                                                            options:NSBackwardsSearch].location;

    if (breakIndex != NSNotFound && breakIndex != theText.length-1) {
        // There is a breakable char in the middle, so draw a URL through that, then break
        // ...
    } else {
        // There is no breakable char (or it's at the end), so start this word on a new line
        // ...
    }
```

The characters in my NSCharacterSet are just ? and -, which I discovered NSLineBreakByWordWrapping breaks on.  It does not break on some other characters I see in URLs like % and =.  Is there a complete list of characters I should be breaking on?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using "not alphanumeric" as your test.

```
[[NSCharacterSet alphanumerCharacterSet] invertedSet]
```

That said, if you're doing a lot of this, you may want to consider using `CTFramesetter` to do your layout instead of `UILabel`. Then you can use `CTRunGetImageBounds` to calculate actual rects. You wouldn't have to calculate your word breaks, since `CTFrame` will already have done this for you (and it would be guaranteed to be the same algorithm).

Comment: I think this will include many characters that are not considered "word boundaries", like % and =.  Neither UILabel nor NSString's `drawInRect: withFont: lineBreakMode:` message break on those.

Comment: I'm using `drawInRect` to draw text on the screen, and then putting tappable `UILabel`s over the URL text when the table cell is selected.  (The tableview scrolls way faster with drawn text than it did with millions of `UILabel`s everywhere.)