# UILineBreakModeWordWrap (or NSLineBreakByWordWrapping) stop from splitting word across 2 lines

Tags: ios, nsstring, uifont

I am trying to work out the biggest font size for a string that will fit within a defined rectangle. Now I have found many other posts that state how to do it including:

[Resizing UILabel to fit with Word Wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520855/resizing-uilabel-to-fit-with-word-wrap)

[Resize CATextLayer to fit text on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198084/resize-catextlayer-to-fit-text-on-ios?rq=1)

[iPhone UILabel sizeWithFont:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204000/iphone-uilabel-sizewithfont/3599071#3599071)

[Which characters does NSLineBreakByWordWrapping break on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118623/which-characters-does-nslinebreakbywordwrapping-break-on)

Now these are great and tell me how to get the biggest font size. However when using the method "sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:" with a line break of (UILineBreakModeWordWrap or NSLineBreakByWordWrapping) it is actually splitting large words across multiple lines.

**Isn't UILineBreakModeWordWrap (or NSLineBreakByWordWrapping) suppose to mean that words don't 'split' over more than one line.** I'm happy for multiple words being on multiple lines, however I don't want a single word to be split across two. If UILineBreakModeWordWrap can't do this, is there something else that can?

Below is the code I use to determine the biggest possible font size: (text is @"australia")

```
-(UIFont *)GetFontSizeForText:(NSString *)text inRect:(CGRect)rect {
    BOOL notFit = YES;
    CGSize textSize;
    CGFloat tmpFontSize = TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE;
    UIFont *tmpFont;    

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    while (notFit) {
        tmpFont = [UIFont fontWithName:TEMPLATE_DEFAULT_FONT_NAME size:tmpFontSize];
        textSize = [text sizeWithFont:tmpFont constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        if (textSize.height > rect.size.height) {
            tmpFontSize -= 1.0;
            if (tmpFontSize < 2.0) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            notFit = NO;
        }
    }

    return tmpFont;
}
```

Below is an image link that shows what happens when using the above function to work out a font size. The 'yellow' box is the biggest size. The purple box is the actual CATextLayer being rendered using the calculated font size. The 'AUSTRALIA' text above these box's is a UILabel that I put on there with interface builder at the same font size.

http://www.connstructstudios.com.au/externalimages/multilines.png

Comment: what UI Component are you trying to achieve this with?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a usual case (a label that is so narrow that it can barely fit one small word on a line).  You should make the label wide enough to accommodate the longest word in a given font size, then you will have no problem with this.  Actually you should make it long enough to fit multiple words!  Of course it is going to wrap if there is not enough space on a single line for a single word.  What else do you expect it to do?

Comment: Hi Guys, I am using this to generate a CATextLayer and putting that onto the screen. So in response to your statements borrrden I am just using this as a sample. However, the box is a 128 by 128 rectangle which is big enough to fit the text 'Australia' in. It just needs to be at font 22px or lower (the code is stopping at font size 44px). As the text is dynamic (user can type it in else where), I need to be able to display their text (shrinking it the more text there is).

Comment: Just a bit more info. The yellow box in the picture is a CALayer (this defines the max rectangle space the text can go in). The purple box and associated text is CATextLayer, with its size being determined by the function I have listed above.

Comment: You will have better luck with a fixed width.  What is the point of shrinking it??  If you make it have a fixed width that is long enough to enclose the longest word then you will never have this problem.

Comment: borrrden. I do have a fixed width. The the user can type what ever they want (its free text!). So they could type something short like 'I like to eat' or they could type something long with many big words 'hippopotamus love developing apps on their machintoshcomputer in australia'. Hence the shrinking of the text so it fits within the pre-defined area.

The problem is that my code shrinks the text to fit it within the area, but it will wrap words over more than one line. If it needs to wrap a word I want it to continue shrinking the font size, till no wrapping occurs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wrapping occurs at word boundaries, unless the word itself doesn’t fit on a single line."

So, a single word can be split if it's too long.

To solve the problem you could separate the string in words, use `- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font;` for each component and check if the width is lower than than max one.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I will try when I get some time. I think what I would do is I would grab the biggest text, and loop on that untill I find a font size big enough for it to fit on one line. Then from there I start the overall text loop (starting with the previously discovered font size) and go from there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks Luis, I now do a sub check with the longest word in the text. This gives me the starting font to which I then proceed to use for the entire text. ;)

Comment: Great to know. Getting a starting font for the longest word seems a quite optimal solution.